# Replace HTML nodes with Cheerio

Tags: javascript, node.js, dom, cheerio

I'm using [Cheerio JS](https://www.google.fi/search?q=cheerio%20js&oq=cheerio%20js&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.1613j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) to simplify some ancient HTML code and transform it into HTML5. Among other things, I'm replacing some markup-heavy quotes that look like the following:

Node to be replaced:

```
<div style="margin:20px; margin-top:5px; ">
    <div class="smallfont" style="margin-bottom:2px">Quote:</div>
    <table cellpadding="6" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="alt2" style="border:1px solid #999">
                    <div>
                        Originally Posted by <strong>Username</strong>
                    </div>
                    <div style="font-style:italic">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

The transformed output is supposed to look like this:

```
<blockquote>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</blockquote>
```

Here's the code current code I'm using at this time:

```
$(`table[id^='post']`).each( (i, el) => {
    // Get the post
    let postBody = $(el).find(`div[id^='post_message_']`).html().trim();

    // Replace quotes with blockquotes
    cheerio.load(postBody)('div[style^="margin:20px; margin-top:5px; "]').each( (i, el) => {
        if ($(el).html().trim().startsWith('<div class="smallfont" style="margin-bottom:2px">Quote')) {
            let tbody = $(el).find('tbody > tr > td').html();
            let quote = $(el).find('tbody > tr > td > div');

            if (quote.html() && quote.text().trim().startsWith('Originally Posted by')) {
                let replacement = $('<blockquote>Hello</blockquote>');
                quote.parent().html().replace(quote.html(), replacement);
            }

            // Looks all good
            console.log($(el).html())
        }

        postBody = $(el).html();
    });
});
```

And lastly, more HTML for some context:

```
<div id="post_message_123456">
    As Username has previously written
    <br>
    <div style="margin:20px; margin-top:5px; ">
        <div class="smallfont" style="margin-bottom:2px">Quote:</div>
        <table cellpadding="6" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td class="alt2" style="border:1px solid #999">

                        <div>
                            Originally Posted by <strong>Username</strong>
                        </div>
                        <div style="font-style:italic">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <br>
    I think he has a point!
    <img src="smile-with-sunglasses.gif" />
</div>
```

The replacement itself seems to work, the output of the `console.log()` statement looks all good. The problem lies in the last line, where I'm trying to replace the original content with the replacement. However, `postBody` looks like it did before. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: There's no `div[id^='post_message_']` element in that html

Comment: @pguardiario How do you know what the markup looks like? I've only posted the part I'd like to replace and mentioned that it's working up until the last line.

Comment: Post html that works with your code please

Comment: Okay, I've updated my question

Answer (score 7):

Try it like this:

```
let $ = cheerio.load(html)

$('.alt2 div:contains("Originally Posted by")')
  .replaceWith('<blockquote>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</blockquote>')

console.log($.html())
```

Answer (score 5):

## Replace items based on individual context

This demonstrates how you could swap out insecure with secure URLs
as a useful real-world example and also make programatic decisions that is much easier to do than with regex for most normal humans.

```
const $ = cheerio.load(html)
// example replace all http:// with https://
$('img[src^="http://"]').replaceWith(function() {
  const src = $(this).attr('src')
  if (src.indexOf('s3.amazon.com')) {
    src = src.replace('s3.amazon.com', 'storage.azure')
  }
  return $(this).attr('src', src.replace('http://', 'https://'))
})
```

Comment: Cheerio doesn't document `replaceWith` as being able to take a function.

Comment: Moved to https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio/blob/main/src/api/manipulation.ts#L617

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to transfer only attributes of the HTML nodes, like link `href` and img `src` or text content, I suggest using Cheerio's `each`  instead of `replaceWith`, as based on my experience, the `replaceWith` is somewhat more problematic for some edge cases. You do not need to replace the element as a whole, you can mutate its attributes and children as you wish.

Example:

```
    $('img').each(function () {
        const $this = $(this);
        let src = $this.attr('rc');
        if (src.indexOf('s3.amazon.com')) {
           src = src.replace('s3.amazon.com', 'storage.azure')
        }
        $this.attr('src', src)
    });
```